# Sort a list of objects depending on a field used for relationship

Tags: python, algorithm

Given the list "data" below, how can we match each element in the list to its corresponding relationship to other elements in the list, each element can only be matched once.

For example:

```
data = [
    {"ID": "A", "RelationIDs": ["B", "C", "D","F", "E"]},
    {"ID": "B", "RelationIDs": ["A", "E"]},
    {"ID": "C", "RelationIDs": ["D"]},
    {"ID": "D", "RelationIDs": ["C"]},
    {"ID": "E", "RelationIDs": ["A", "B"]},
    {"ID": "F", "RelationIDs": ["A", "B", "C"]},
    {"ID": "G", "RelationIDs": []},
    {"ID": "H", "RelationIDs": []},
]
```

The output should be:

```
A is reserved with F
B is reserved with E
C is reserved with D
G is reserved with H
```

So RelationIDs is the list of ID's that the element is *allowed* to be matched with, once either of the element's have been matched it cannot be matched again for another element.

Most importantly ensuring every element has a match. For example we cannot match A with B (even though they are allowed by each other) because then F would not have anything to be matched with, as by the time we check F the elements would have been.

"G" is reserved with "H" as neither of them have any existing relationship, so they can create a new relationship together.

for explanation purposes I'm assuming the output above is a match/print(). The data list can get more longer, I've included only 8 elements here. The main issue is ensuring we are matching elements in the most optimal way, we don't want to match X element with Y element, if X element has other possible matches, and Y element is only Z elements match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of elements, each of which specifies other elements it can be paired with. The challenge is to find a valid pairing for all elements under the condition that once an element is paired, it cannot be paired again, and the pairs should be as optimal as possible considering available matches.

```
import itertools

data = [
    {"ID": "A", "RelationIDs": ["B", "C", "D","F", "E"]},
    {"ID": "B", "RelationIDs": ["A", "E"]},
    {"ID": "C", "RelationIDs": ["D"]},
    {"ID": "D", "RelationIDs": ["C"]},
    {"ID": "E", "RelationIDs": ["A", "B"]},
    {"ID": "F", "RelationIDs": ["A", "B", "C"]},
    {"ID": "G", "RelationIDs": []},
    {"ID": "H", "RelationIDs": []},
]

def is_valid_pair(a, b):
    return (b in a["RelationIDs"] or not a["RelationIDs"]) and \
           (a in b["RelationIDs"] or not b["RelationIDs"])

def find_optimal_pairs(data):
    unmatched = data.copy()
    pairs = []

    while unmatched:
        found_match = False
        for a, b in itertools.combinations(unmatched, 2):
            if is_valid_pair(a, b):
                pairs.append((a["ID"], b["ID"]))
                unmatched = [x for x in unmatched if x["ID"] != a["ID"] and x["ID"] != b["ID"]]
                found_match = True
                break

        if not found_match:
            print(f"No match found for {unmatched[0]['ID']}")
            return pairs
        
    return pairs

pairs = find_optimal_pairs(data)

for a, b in pairs:
    print(f"{a} is reserved with {b}")
```

Implement a function in Python that checks all possible pair combinations, validates them against allowed matches, and selects pairs iteratively, removing used elements to ensure they're not reused.

REF - https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: thanks Bimesh, I ended up building upon your code which worked well for my use case. Note to others: is_valid_pair() has a typo the"in" statements are missing the ["ID"] key.

Answer (score 3):

This is a graph problem. Your data defines a graph, with one vertex for each ID, and one edge between two vertices if these two IDs have a relationship.

You are looking for a maximum [marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) in this graph.

I suggest using graph library [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html):

```py
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.matching import max_weight_matching

data = [
    {"ID": "A", "RelationIDs": ["B", "C", "D","F", "E"]},
    {"ID": "B", "RelationIDs": ["A", "E"]},
    {"ID": "C", "RelationIDs": ["D"]},
    {"ID": "D", "RelationIDs": ["C"]},
    {"ID": "E", "RelationIDs": ["A", "B"]},
    {"ID": "F", "RelationIDs": ["A", "B", "C"]},
    {"ID": "G", "RelationIDs": []},
    {"ID": "H", "RelationIDs": []},
]

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_vertices_from(d['ID'] for d in data)
G.add_edges_from((d['ID'], v) for d in data for v in d['RelationIDs'])

m = max_weight_matching(G, maxcardinality=True)

print(m)
# {('D', 'C'), ('E', 'A'), ('F', 'B')}
```

Comment: I think "matching" is the proper/common term, not marriage.

Comment: @KellyBundy As far as I know these two terms are both proper and common.

Comment: The article you linked to says "matching" 137 times and "marriage" 2 times. Your program says "matching" 3 times and "marriage" 0 times.

Comment: @KellyBundy My program uses function names from library networkx. The article I linked was written by someone who prefers "matching" to "marriage" and they decided to stay consistent and use only one of the two terms throughout the article. I don't see how that makes "marriage" improper.

Comment: And both "marriage" occurrences in the article are just references to other articles, where the name makes sense because it's about matching two sets, thought of as men and women. That's not the case here.

Comment: @KellyBundy So you're saying that "marriage" is only proper in the particular case of matching in a bipartite graph?

Comment: That's at least how I know it, yes.

Comment: Although with gay marriage becoming more common, this origin/background becomes less compelling. Maybe one day enough people will complain and rewrite the graph theory books :-). Like when "master" branches in Git were renamed to "main".